# How do I do anything?

Tags: user-interface

I've installed Linux for the first time, and I've chosen Elementary because it's quite 'mac-like.' I'm a lifelong Mac user. I've spent an age getting Elementary to recognise my bluetooth trackpad and keyboard - success. And I've downloaded an app using Firefox. But where's the download? Where is the Firefox menu which would open the download destination?
For that matter, where is my home folder? If I create any files, where will they go?
I'm a long time Apple user, so I expect to see a Finder, documents, icons. There's none of this. Is there a basic intro for a Mac user trying to get to grips with this OS? Or can anyone tell me how I get access to the hard drive and the files and directories / folders on it?

Answer (score 0):

The linux world is probably more foreign to the Apple demographic even than Windows.

[Try this tutorial.](https://elementary.io/docs/learning-the-basics#learning-the-basics) It's a good starter. It sounds like you might answer most of your questions by clicking on Files and looking around.